# How to use & run an existing yeoman project?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

After cloning an existing **yeoman** project in a new computer, how to build and run the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use an existing **yeoman** project:

**For the first time:**

- install **node.js** http://nodejs.org/ *(if windows add it to `PATH`)*
- install **grunt bower yeoman** `npm install -g yo bower grunt-cli`
- *if using compass* 
  -- *(if windows or linux)* install **ruby**  http://rubyinstaller.org/ *(if windows add it to
  `PATH`)*
  -- change the *gem* source to *http* `gem source -r http://rubygems.org` *(if SSL error)*
  -- install *compass*  `gem install compass`

**Then:**

- `npm install`
- `bower install`

**Finally**

- `grunt serve` to launch the *webapp*

Comment: Why do you need ruby? I've run /yo with no ruby installed